# How to get Traffic acquisition report of my GA4 account using Google Analytics Data API (GA4)?

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get the statistics from my Google Analytics account (GA4) related to Traffic acquisition. Like from where user came to my website, organically or direct or threw social media.

I have added the `google/analytics-data` package to this Google document:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

```
composer require google/analytics-data
```

I have all the required detail like property id and service account json file.

This is the code i have mange:

```
    putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$this->config_file_path");
        $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
        $credentials = ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials();
        $analyticsData = new AlphaAnalyticsDataClient(['credentials' => $credentials]);

        // Create a date range for the report.
        $dateRanges = [
            new DateRange([
                'start_date' => '2023-07-21',
                'end_date' => 'today',
            ]),
        ];

        $dimensions = [new Dimension(
            [
                'name' => 'source',
            ],
            ),
            new Dimension(
                [
                    'name' => 'medium',
                ]
            ),
            new Dimension(
                [
                    'name' => 'country',
                ]
            ),
        ];
        $metrics = [new Metric(
            [
                'name' => 'sessions',
            ]
        ),
           
        ];

        $response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $this->property_id,
            'dateRanges' => $dateRanges,
            'dimensions' => $dimensions,
            'metrics' => $metrics,
        ]);

        foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getDimensionValues()[1]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getDimensionValues()[2]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue(). PHP_EOL;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
```

But getting **empty** result.

Please help me with this or point out where i have to improve my code to get the result, as i can see the detail in my account but not getting threw **Google Analytics Data API (GA4)**

Comment: Try this package (https://github.com/zfhassaan/genlytics)

Comment: is it compatible with GA4 and sorry for asking but i am using laravel 8, is it comatible with that , sorry if my question did not seems correct

Comment: You can try with Laravel 8 and yes it's compatible with GA4. I have used it with laravel 9 and laravel 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Dimension(
                [
                    'name' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup',
                ]
            ),
            new Dimension(
                [
                    'name' => 'country',
                ]
            ),
        ];
        $metrics = [new Metric(
            [
                'name' => 'sessions',
            ]
        ),
           
        ];
       $dimensionFilter = new DimensionFilter([
           'dimension_name' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup',
            'operator' => 'EXACT',
            'expressions' => ['Organic Search'],
       ]);
       $dimensionFilters = [$dimensionFilter];

       

        $response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $this->property_id,
            'dateRanges' => $dateRanges,
            'dimensions' => $dimensions,
            'metrics' => $metrics,
            'dimensionFilter' => $dimensionFilters,
        ]);

        foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getDimensionValues()[1]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getDimensionValues()[2]->getValue()
                . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue(). PHP_EOL;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
```

Explanation :
if you want to find Referral Traffic from GA4, you need to add ***sessionDefaultChannelGroup*** to your dimensionFilter like below

```
  $dimensionFilter = new DimensionFilter([
               'dimension_name' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGroup',
                'operator' => 'EXACT',
                'expressions' => ['Organic Search'],
           ]);
```

Comment: hello, please could you edit your answer to explain your code for the benefit of future readers of this question? thanks in advance!

Comment: @always-a-learner - If you found this answer right, mark this answer right!

Answer (score -1):

Because traffic source uses session source and session medium not session and medium dimensions

[image]

Comment: So what changes i have to made ?

Comment: use sessionSource and sessionMedium and see what happends